# How do I determine the proper return for initsessionidtype in db2secGetAuthIDs

Tags: db2, db2-luw

We are implementing a custom security plugin for Db2 11.5. In the implementation of the `db2secGetAuthIDs` there is a return for `initsessionidtype`. See the documentation here:(https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/r0012032.html)

It details that the possible return values are:

```
DB2SEC_ID_TYPE_AUTHID (0)
DB2SEC_ID_TYPE_ROLE (1)
```

Should `DB2SEC_ID_TYPE_AUTHID` be returned based on if that authid exists in the user registry - otherwise return `DB2SEC_ID_TYPE_ROLE` or is there additional context that would need to be handled?

Comment: The sample code in `gssapi_simple.c` for `db2secGetAuthIDs` has the line `*initsessionidtype = 0;       /* TBD ?! --sil */` .  Suggests that it is not only yourself puzzled by this documentation. However, that value seems safe, as you will know whether your plugin has special processing for roles.  Maybe open a ticket with IBM support, as getting documentation changes for Db2-LUW is a currently impossible task, there's nobody home!

Answer (score 0):

After engaging with the directly with the IBM Db2 team the answer is that you only need to ever set `*initsessionidtype` to `DB2SEC_ID_TYPE_AUTHID` as that is the only type that is available. Anything else will return an error.